# how do I call an element in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
a= int(input())
# I input 12345
b = a
list(map(int, b))
print (list[0]*2+list[3]*1)
#can't seem to get 6 as my answer
```

how do I attain my answer? I can't seem to call the elements in the list. Thank you for your help.

Comment: review you code first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're treating the input as individual digits, you should avoid converting the input to an integer as a whole, but map the individual digits to integers as a sequence of characters:

```
a= input()
b = list(map(int, a))
print(b[0] * 2 + b[3] * 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why your code won't work, including your use of the map function, the fact that you do not assign the result to a variable and the use of list  (which is a keyword in Python).

However, consider this code snippet which calculates your desired output:

```
a = int(input('Enter a number: '))

b = [int(digit) for digit in str(a)]

res = 2 * b[0] + b[3]

print(res)
```

Basically you have to transform your integer into a string to be able to iterate over it. Afterwards you create your list of digits out of it and can do your calculations.

Generally speaking, you should learn the basics of Python properly. A good starting point would be the official documentation ([LINK](https://www.python.org/doc/)).